# Struggle to understand time-complexity. Where do my reasoning fail?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm a university student majoring in Data Science, and we're currently discussing time-complexity. I could already code in Python before my studies, but I've never payed much attention to time efficiency, and I have never studied Big-O notation before. It seems like, in many exercises, I'm always close to the solution but my answer is never right.

Take for example this Python code:

```py
def fun(N, M):
    S1 = set(N)
    S2 = set(M)
    res = []
    for x in S1:
        if x in S2:
            for i in range(N.count(x)):
                res.append(x)
    return res
```

Say length of *N* is *n* and length of *M* is *m*. My reasoning is the following:

- `for x in S1` is at worst *O(n)* because it loops at worst *n* times
- `if x in S2` is at worst *O(m)* because at worst it makes *m* comparisons
- `N.count(x)` is *O(n)* because - worst case - it will perform *n* operations (while counting the occurrences of *x* in *N*)
- finally the `.append()` operation is performed *n* times (as I said above)

If I'm correct, complexity should be *O(n<sup>3</sup>m)*.
Yet, the correct solution is *O(n<sup>2</sup>+ m)*

Can you help me understanding where my reasoning fails? 
I'm sorry if my question may seem obvious or naive, I'm not that experienced in thinking in complexity terms.

Comment: `x in S2` is O(1) for sets.

Comment: Okay, my bad for for  ```x in S2```. Knowing that, solution would be O(n^3), right? About the correct solution, I'm as surprised as you, it's just the solution provided by professor.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the complexity for all lines:

```
def fun(N, M):
    S1 = set(N) # O(n)
    S2 = set(M) # O(m)
    res = [] # O(1)
    for x in S1: # O(n) * ... SEE CORRECTION
        if x in S2: # O(1)
            for i in range(N.count(x)): # O(n) * ... SEE CORRECTION
                res.append(x) # O(1)
    return res # O(1)
```

Then put it together:

```
O(n + m + 1 + n*(1+n*1) + 1) = O(n**2 + m)
```

Correction / subtleties:

`N.count(x)` is always `O(n)`, but it's `O(N)+...` not `O(n)*...`. The `*` complexity depends on the *value* of `N.count(x)` not its complexity.
Think of it as:

```
k = N.count(x) # O(n)
for i in range(k): # O(k)*...
```

instead of:

```
for i in range(N.count(x)): # O(???)
```

Then what I wrote is the worst case (although with a very misleading  shortcut) when all elements in `N` are different. In that case `for x in S1:` is really `O(n)*...` but then `k = N.count(x) = 1` for all `x` so `for i in range(N.count(x)):` is `O(n) + O(1)*...` (not `O(n)*...`) still leading to `O(n + m + 1 + n*(1+n+1*1) + 1) = O(n**2 + m)`.

In the best case however when all elements in `N` are identical, then there is only one value for `x` so `for x in S1:` is `O(1)*...`, but also `k = N.count(x) = n` for that unique `x`. so `for i in range(N.count(x)):` is `O(n) + O(n)*...` now leading to `O(n + m + 1 + 1*(1+n+n*1) + 1) = O(n + m)`.

(But you typically shouldn't focus on best case complexity.)

Comment: Hey, can you pls explain why will x in S2 have O(1)? Thanks

Comment: Sets (and dicts) use hash maps to check for `in` which is O(1). I'm not going to explain that in a comment, but there are numerous pages that do it already if you search for it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Didn't know something like ```S = set(N)``` is O(n). Also, writing complexity next to all lines is probably a good idea to start

Comment: If `N` is a list then `N.count(x)` takes `O(N)` time, you forgot to mention this significant extra time.

Comment: @Arty He didn't mention it but its not significant. It would just change the final expression from `O(n + m + 1 + n*(1+n*1) + 1)` to `O(n + m + 1 + n*(1+n+n*1) + 1)` i.e. adding another O(n) operation to a loop which already contained an O(n) operation.

Comment: @inordirection In a sense of time complexity yes final order `O(n^2 + m)` will remain the same, but if not to remove `constant` multiplyer from complexity then you will get twice bigger time, instead of `O(n^2 + m)` you will get `O(2 * n^2 + m)`, twice bigger, which is significant. Anyway he mentioned precise time, and even included `O(1)`, but extra `O(N)` he forgot to include, which is significant I think.

Comment: @Arty True, it's good to point out. I just thought you meant "significant" in terms of impacting the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @Arty by definition O(2*n) = O(n) since constant factors are _defined_ as insignificant. If you care about them then you shouldn't use the big O notation... That said, yes I did gloss over some subtleties, see edit.

Comment: @Julien Yes, although in O-notation constants are usually ommitted, I just mentioned this extra `O(N)` for count only because you were very precise to included all the `O(1)` but forgot this `O(N)` which is more significant than `O(N)`.